# How to apply class level validation rules using the Angular implementation of jQuery Validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-validate, angular-validation

I have used jQuery Validate's handy [addClassRules](https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addClassRules/) function to apply a rule to all elements of a given class rather than relying on the elements' `name` attribute values. In using the [Angular wrapper of jQuery Validate](https://github.com/jpkleemans/angular-validate), I've found that the `addClassRules` function is not supported out of the box. I tried modifying `angular-validate.js` to bring in this functionality, but no luck. The file is small, so I'll paste the whole thing, with my modification, below. Skip to the TL;DR at the end if you prefer.

#### angular-validate.js (with one modification)

```
(function (angular, $) {
    angular.module('ngValidate', [])

        .directive('ngValidate', function () {
            return {
                require: 'form',
                restrict: 'A',
                scope: {
                    ngValidate: '='
                },
                link: function (scope, element, attrs, form) {
                    var validator = element.validate(scope.ngValidate);
                    form.validate = function (options) {
                        var oldSettings = validator.settings;
                        validator.settings = $.extend(true, {}, validator.settings, options);
                        var valid = validator.form();
                        validator.settings = oldSettings; // Reset to old settings
                        return valid;
                    };
                    form.numberOfInvalids = function () {
                        return validator.numberOfInvalids();
                    };
                }
            };
        })

    .provider('$validator', function () {
        $.validator.setDefaults({
            onsubmit: false // to prevent validating twice
        });

        return {
            setDefaults: $.validator.setDefaults,
            addMethod: $.validator.addMethod,
            addClassRules: $.validator.addClassRules, /*<< this is the line I added >>*/
            setDefaultMessages: function (messages) {
                angular.extend($.validator.messages, messages);
            },
            format: $.validator.format,
            $get: function () {
                return {};
            }
        };
    });
}(angular, jQuery));
```

I only get an error if I actually try to invoke the `addClassRules` function in code. For example:

```
angular.module("PageModule", ['ngValidate'])
    .config(function($validatorProvider) {
        $validatorProvider.setDefaults({
            errorClass: "error custom-error-class" // this works fine
        })
        $validatorProvider.addMethod("customValidationMethod", function (value) {
                var isValid = false;
                // do stuff
                return isValid;
            }, "Bleh"
        ); // this works fine too
        $validatorProvider.addClassRules("emailField", {
            email: true
        }); // this crashes :(
    });
```

And the error is [as follows](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=PageModule&p1=TypeError:%20Cannot%20set%20property%20%27emailField%27%20of%20undefined%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Object.addClassRules%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:54874%2FScripts%2Fjquery.validate.js:938:40)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost:54874%2FFranchisee%2FProposals%2FHours%3FPropNo%3D49090.7:192:36%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Object.e%20%5Bas%20invoke%5D%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:54874%2FScripts%2Fangular.min.js:39:193)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20d%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:54874%2FScripts%2Fangular.min.js:37:374)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost:54874%2FScripts%2Fangular.min.js:37:498%0A%20%20%20%20at%20m%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:54874%2FScripts%2Fangular.min.js:7:322)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:54874%2FScripts%2Fangular.min.js:37:275)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20fb%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:54874%2FScripts%2Fangular.min.js:41:35)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20d%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:54874%2FScripts%2Fangular.min.js:19:463)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20yc%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:54874%2FScripts%2Fangular.min.js:20:274):

[image: Angular Validate error in Chrome JS console]

Is there a way for me to use jQuery Validate's `addClassRules` function within its [Angular implementation](https://github.com/jpkleemans/angular-validate)? What modification might I need to make? Or, is there a better way to apply validation rules to multiple elements on something other than the `name` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have used jQuery Validate's handy `addClassRules` function to apply a rule to all elements of a given class ...

That's not the issue the [`.addClassRules()`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addClassRules/) method was meant to solve.  It's used for combining multiple standard rules into a *single* "compound" rule that can be applied using *one* class name.

---

> Or, is there a better way to apply validation rules to multiple elements on something other than the `name` attribute?

If you simply want to apply individual rules using class names, the plugin is smart enough to pick those up and no special techniques or methods are needed.

```
<input type="text" class="required email" name="foo" ...
```

By simply using the `required` and `email` classes, you have automatically applied the `required` and `email` rules to this field.

DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/70g6brcf/](http://jsfiddle.net/70g6brcf/)

---

Alternatively, you can use HTML5 attributes and the plugin will apply rules accordingly.

```
<input type="email" required="required" name="foo" ...
```

DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/70g6brcf/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/70g6brcf/1/)

---

**NOTE**:  These are only alternative ways to apply rules.  [These methods do not negate the requirement to have a `name` attribute, which is mandatory when using jQuery Validate](https://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/#link-markup-recommendations).

Comment: Thanks for the info, you've given me a bit to look into. As for having to have a `name` attribute, why do you say that? In my case, I have dozens of `input` elements in the same form that need the same validation. I have no need of `name` attributes, and I certainly don't want to duplicate names. Besides, I'm posting the form using `$scope` model properties, not traditional posting. I've had no problem omitting `name` attributes in the past, even with jQuery Validate. As for applying individual rules using class names, I'll give that a go, but I don't like how invasive that is of the CSS.

Comment: @JacobStamm, I don't recall saying it was ok to duplicate a `name` attribute.  However, if you think you can use jQuery Validate without `name` attributes, try it:  http://jsfiddle.net/zxhu17ja/ ~ Or just read the documentation:  [*"Mandated: A 'name' attribute is required for all input elements needing validation, and the plugin will **not** work without this."*](https://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/#link-markup-recommendations)

Comment: I know that I've gotten jQuery Validate to work fine without `name` attributes before, but you're right, the documentation is clear. I probably just got lucky in my implementation :) . About the resolution: I know the CSS classes would work fine, but I don't want accidental styles to get applied at some point, so I'm going with the `data-` attributes. I also got rid of my `addClassRules` stuff and am using my custom method, named "hours", directly, by putting `data-rule-hours="true"` on the elements. I also filled in some bs `name` values that are unique. Everything's working great :)

Comment: @JacobStamm, you're welcome  and I'm glad everything is resolved for now.  However, lucky or not, it's impossible that you got this plugin working without `name` attributes.  There are over 6000 SO questions tagged with jQuery Validate and [I've personally answered 25% of them](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:594235%20[jquery-validate]%20is:answer)... the issue has been beaten to death.  Otherwise, myself and others would be very interested in how you accomplished this.

Comment: I'll take your word on that one. For all I know, my server-side HTML preprocessing was adding `name` attributes without me noticing on the client-side.